# How to make SqlDataReader to get time(7) type variable?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table like this:

```
userID int
xCoordinate int
yCoordinate int
recordTime time(7)
itemId int
```

I want to get all recording times of a given user (let's say user 1 for now).
I used the following code for this:

```
public static void something()
{
    string stmt = "select * from GazeTable where id = " + 1 + " ;";

    SqlConnection conn = GetConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stmt, conn);

    conn.Open();

    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetDateTime(3));
        }
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

But it throws an error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.dll

saying, this assignment is not valid.

How can I print the time in terms of ("HH:mm:ss.ffff"), for each `recordTime` in my table?

Comment: Is it working to get y coordinate with `reader.GetInt(2)`?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the SQL Type `Time(7)` does not convert to `DateTime` but `TimeSpan` in C#, so try `reader.GetTimeSpan(3)` instead

Comment: @ntohl yes it does

Comment: @BojanB oh my god it worked, everywhere i searched, kept saying, datetime is the equivalent of sql's time, thank you so much

Comment: @Danabey no prob :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL Type `Time(7)` is equivalent to the C# Type `TimeSpan` not `DateTime`, to get a `DateTime` Value the SQL Type has to be `datetime`.

So just change your code to read TimeSpan instead of DateTime:

```
public static void something()
{
   string stmt = "select * from GazeTable where id = " + 1 + " ;";
   SqlConnection conn = GetConnection();
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stmt, conn);

   conn.Open();
   using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {
      while (reader.Read())
      {
         Console.WriteLine(reader.GetTimeSpan(3));
      }
   }
   conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: A cast may be needed `(SqlDataReader)reader` the `GetTimeSpan` is not available in `System.Data.IDataReader`

Answer (score 0):

Out of the top of my head, you might need to use something like this (haven't tested):

```
    public static void something()
    {
        string stmt = "select * from GazeTable where id = " + 1 + " ;";

        SqlConnection conn = GetConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stmt, conn);

        conn.Open();
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", ((SqlDataReader)reader).GetTimeSpan(3).ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss\:ff"));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

You should convert the time(7) column to a timespan, you can't convert it directly to a datetime.

Comment: probably this will work too, but i will ensure that there is no `Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");` case. so thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you are using the .NET Framework 4.8 or earlier GetTimeSpan() is not available.  Instead you must use (TimeSpan)reader.GetValue(columnIndex)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35089984)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).